# How to change header of word file by Drop-down list

Tags: vba, ms-word

I would like to change title of my header based on a drop down by using macro help.

I am trying to find all the items in my word file by below code but it seems that the text box in my header is not coming in ActiveDocument.ContentControls list. would you mind help me to solve my problem.

My "test" message never appear.

```
For Each oCC In ActiveDocument.ContentControls
    If oCC.Tag = "CB_DOC_TYP" Then
        MsgBox "doc Type"

        For Each oDD In ActiveDocument.ContentControls
            If oDD.Tag = "TB_Header_Titel" Then
                oDD.SetPlaceholderText , , oCC.Title
                MsgBox "test"
            End If
        Next oDD
    End If
End If
```

Answer (score 1):

Header is different part of the document. When calling `ActiveDocument.ContentControl` you search by default in `wdMainTextStory` section. To get your content control which is in header try one of the references:

```
ActiveDocument.StoryRanges(wdPrimaryHeaderStory).ContentControls
```

or

```
ActiveDocument.StoryRanges(wdEvenPagesHeaderStory).ContentControls
```

or

```
ActiveDocument.StoryRanges(wdFirstPageHeaderStory).ContentControls
```

You can also loop through all document story ranges in this way:

```
Dim SR As Object
For Each SR In ActiveDocument.StoryRanges

    'your macro here
    '....

Next
```

Comment: I tried but it is not working...count for all above 3 story range is come as 0.
ActiveDocument.StoryRanges(wdEvenPagesHeaderStory).ContentControls.Count

Comment: which means that you don't have any ContentControls in your headers. Check it with with proposed loop- add inside the loop the following line: `Debug.Print SR.ContentControls.Count` and check if sum of all result equals to number of ContentControls you have.

Comment: I run below code
  Dim SR As Object
    For Each SR In ActiveDocument.StoryRanges
       Debug.Print SR.ContentControls.Count
       MsgBox (SR.ContentControls.Count)
    Next SR
first msg box is come as 13 and the ramain is 0.

Comment: which means that all your content controls are in one story range, possibly in main text area. Nothing in headers.

Comment: but my text field available in header. when I double click on header to edit header it is there. would you mind help me to how check it is there or not!?

Comment: you need to upload your file somewhere in the web and provide link to your document that I could download it and check.